# How do I compute the maximum number of skip-grams Keras's skipgram function could generate?

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I am looking to create a function to generate a batch of skipgrams with Keras' skipgrams function, but to do this, I need to know how many skipgrams Keras could possibly generate.

Comment: Why would you need the number of skipgrams in order to use the `skipgrams` function? That's not a requirement to use the function.

Comment: @thushv89: No, but I'm creating a function to generate batches, and am looking to try to make the process as efficient as possible. The biggest bottlenect in my program is figuring out exactly how many skipgrams I need to allocate a numpy array for, so i'm looking to make that as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a corpus of size `n` a window size of `m`, so that the total window size considered at a given time is `2m+1`. Then the number of skip grams would be,

```
2m (n-2m)
```

Let's take a simple example,

`[I like to go to the beach in the winter]`

Here we have `n=10` and assume `m=3`. Then you get,

`2m (n-2m) = 24`

And the word pairs,

```
go, [I | like | to | to | the | beach]
to, [like | to | go | the | beach | in]
the, [to | go | to | beach | in | the]
beach, [go | to | the | in | the | winter]
```

Which is `24`

**PS**: This gives the count of positive skip-gram samples. If you need it with negative, it will be,

```
2m (n-2m) + (n-2m)[n - (2m + 1)] = (n-2m)(n - 1)
```

Comment: So the below formula will give me the number of positive samples AND of negative samples?